# Using HTML5 application cache in a laravel application

Tags: php, html, caching, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering how is it possible to make use of the application cache in order to store a form data into cache when form is submitted in case user loses internet connection. The difficulty here is that the views are loaded by laravel and once the connection is lost I am not sure how to load the views.